# HTML text input tags generated with javascript do not POST when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

I have a form which asks for employment history, where you have applied to college etc. So for example for colleges they applied to I have one text box at first and there is a button below that calls a javascript function to add another text input right below it.  When I first made this form I was doing that with a few different pieces of data then once they were submitted I would get them from `$_POST` and put them in arrays then add each element of the array to the corresponding table in my db.  All of a sudden though, I can no longer submit my form and I get a message telling me that I have tried to get an unspecified index.  However when i inspect the text inputs in my browser they are correctly named.  I read that I should name them `college[]` so that they all go into an array, but that also did not work.... now what?

js:

```
var numcol = 1;
function addnewschool(){
 numcol++;
 var container = document.getElementById("collegecontainer");
 container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(numcol));
 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.type = "text";
 input.name = 'applied'+numcol;
 container.appendChild(input);
 container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));}
```

html:

```
<p class="text-dark mb-4">List the Colleges you have applied to:<br>
<div id="collegecontainer" name="collegecontainer">
<input type="text" name='applied1'><br>
</div>
<input type="button" id="addcollege" name="addcollege" value="Add College" 
onClick="addnewschool()"><br>
</p>
```

php:

```
$applied = array();
foreach($_POST['applied'] as $value){
  array_push($applied, $value);
}
```

Update: Ok so I changed it to another way and that didn't work so i decided to just copy an earlier version of it which was working and paste it into the correct layout.  And that worked... SO now that it was fixed i continued adding to it.  I added "required" to a few tags, changed some styling a bit, and changed my javascript file a bit.  But now I'm having the same issues as before.  All of my POST arrays only have the first value in them.  What could I have added that changed this? Has anyone ever had any issues like this?

Comment: Just use `applied[]` as `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first additional input should have index "applied1", not "applied2"

look at:

```
var numcol = 1; // put this to 0
function addnewschool(){
numcol++; // or move this to the end of the function
```

Comment: nah because thats the name of the one already on the html form.  then the first added one is applied2

Comment: This would change nothing

Answer (score 0):

Name your text input field(s) `applied[]` and when you process the form the post value of `$_POST['applied']` will be an array already filled for you with however many entries were completed.

To get the data into your table:

```
foreach ($_POST['applied'] as $id => $applied) { 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Colleges(id, college) VALUES('$id','$applied')"; 

    if($conn2->query($sql) === TRUE){ 
        echo "New Record created successfully"; 
    } else { 
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn2->error; 
    } 
}  // end of foreach
```

Comment: Yeah so thats what I just tried before I posted this question.  How do I go from having them in that array to putting them in my sql db's table

Comment: Because when i tried to access elements of the array I had an issue so then I tried to print the whole array with print_r($applied) that didnt work so i tried print_r(array_values($applied) and still nothing

Comment: That is going to be outside the scope of this question. You'll want to make an attempt at it and come back with a different question if you run into problems. Hint, loop through the array and add your records in your loop (`foreach` is your friend).

Comment: Use `print_r($_POST['applied']`

Comment: for($i = 0; $i<$numapplied; $i++){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO Colleges(id, college) VALUES('$id','$applied[$i]');";
   if($conn2->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "New Record created successfully";
   }else{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn2->error;
   }
  }

Comment: something like that?

Comment: becasue thats what i started with and it worked for the first week or two

Comment: See the update to my answer and if it works please accept it.

Comment: oh ok interesting let me try that out although, $id is the same for all of the colleges it is the id of the student not the college so I think I would use $value instead...right?

Comment: You didn't provide enough information so to answer would be guessing. As I said, if you get the values you need via the form and have problems getting it into your table the way you want it come back with the code and start another question. The question you asked here has been answered me thinks.

Comment: It has not, I already knew about this approach but all it gives me is the first element which does not help me

Comment: If that's the case you need to take a closer look at your form and make sure it is doing what you think it is. Changing the field name to `applied[]` WILL result in what you are looking for and the `$_POST['applied']` variable will contain more than 1 value if more than one was entered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a different name for each input. Just use `applied[]` in all input names.

To get the array in PHP, just use `$_POST['applied']`.

If you want to use each of them later, you could use a `foreach`, like

```
foreach ($_POST['applied'] as $value) {
    // Do what you want. Retrieve the value using $value
}
```

Or any other method you prefer.

Comment: ok so when i do that is it supposed to be like an advanced for loop in java where it loops through each element in the array? because this is giving me only the first one just as before.

Comment: What are you doing exactly? I've tried it and it works for me

Comment: The form is an application to a scholarship.  So I am storing each college in a table along with an foreign key($id) that references the table where the applicant's personal info is stored.  But when I do this:  foreach($_POST['applied'] as $value){
    echo $value;
  } the only think that is printed is the first college i typed.

Comment: Am I just missing something?

Comment: It's strange. I've tried foreach ($_POST['applied'] as $value) {
    print $value."<br />";
} and it's working. I can understand what is wrong.

Comment: Have you changed JS `input.name` to `applied[]` ?

Comment: Yeah this is a dilemma I have exactly that but when I have 4 inputs all 100% called applied[] filled with "College1", "College2","College3","College4" respectively, the only thing that prints is College1

Comment: yup :(          
var numcol = 1;
function addnewschool(){
  numcol++;
  var container = document.getElementById("collegecontainer");
  container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(numcol));
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.name = 'applied[]';
  container.appendChild(input);
  container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

Comment: If you want, you can compare your code with the code I've used to test, and try to see what's happening. https://gist.github.com/altrisi/9efc20aaa7214cdd2310d49db09614c3